# Recursive method to evaluate a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, recursive-algorithms

I want to find a recursive way of evaluating any polynomial (I'm given the polynomial, and a value for x, and I need to replace the x in the polynomial with the value). The polynomial can be anything, and the x-value will be an integer. Say, $$3x^5+9x^3-2x^2+x$$ and x=5.

What would be the most efficient way of computing the value?

Comment: What do you mean to solve a polynomial?  Usually one solves equations.  Do you want to factor it?  Find a (or all) the roots?  Most numerical analysis books will have a chapter on this.

Comment: Will any solution do, or do you want a particular one, or do you want all the solutions? Do you want a real solution, and if you do, do you know that such a solution exists in advance, or do you need to check?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I will be given the value of x as well (I've also edited the question).

Comment: Edits have clarified that the question was about evaluating the polynomial rather than solving it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want to evaluate a polynomial at a given point.

Try using [Horner's Method](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/hornermod.html).

Comment: That does seem to be what is meant.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into [Horner's Method][1] and [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: Euler's method is for solving differential equations.  There is no differential equation here.

Comment: @Robert: You know, you're right. I got my names mixed up. I meant Horner's Method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme) too.

Answer (score 0):

double p1(double *s, double x, int n)
/*  recursive version */
{
    double peval;
    int i;

```
if (n==0) return s[0];
else
    return s[n]*power(x,n)+p1(s,x,n-1);
```

}